# What is a 'rect style object' and how do I implement it into my code?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn python by making a space game where you travel around the map fighting enemies(drones) that are randomly placed around the map. So far I have been successful in moving the playable spaceship around the map(with rotation), firing lasers, and blitting drones around the map(The drones follow the spaceship around). Though I don't entirely understand classes, I seem to have been able to pull it off so far.

Now, I want to input enemy hp with Laser/Drone collision. I gave the Drone class `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` and called an instance of it in the Laser1 class using `self.c = pygame.Rect.colliderect(drone.rect)` but it just gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "space.py", line 85, in <module>
    blist.append(Laser1 (beamx, beamy))
  File "space.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.c = pygame.Rect.colliderect(drone.rect)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
```

I have searched a lot online for a way to fix this but I don't understand it much and nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
class Drone:

    def __init__(self, dronex, droney):
        self.x = dronex
        self.y = droney
        self.hp = dronehp
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Androne.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

dlist = []
for i in range(10):
    dronex = random.randint(0, 7700)
    droney = random.randint(0, 4520)
    dronehp = 3
    dlist.append(Drone (dronex, droney))

drone = Drone(dronex, droney) #-----------instance i think...

class Roid:

    def __init__(self, roidx, roidy):
        self.x = roidx
        self.y = roidy
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)

rlist = []
for i in range(811):
    roidx = random.randint(-1000, 9104)
    roidy = random.randint(-800, 7200)
    rlist.append(Roid (roidx, roidy))

class Laser1:

    def __init__(self, beamx, beamy):
        self.x = beamx
        self.y = beamy
        self.laser1 = pygame.image.load("laser1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.laser1.get_rect()
        self.c = pygame.Rect.colliderect(drone.rect) #---line 79...

blist = []
for i in range(2):
    beamx = batx
    beamy = baty
    blist.append(Laser1 (beamx, beamy)) #---line 85...

class Laser2:

    def __init__(self, beamx2, beamy2):
        self.x2 = beamx2
        self.y2 = beamy2
        self.laser1 = pygame.image.load("laser1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.laser1.get_rect()
        self.c = pygame.Rect.colliderect(drone.rect)

b2list = []
for i in range(2):
    beamx2 = batx
    beamy2 = baty
    b2list.append(Laser2 (beamx2, beamy2))
```

Also, this is my first question to ask on here. If there is anything I can do to make this question better do tell. I will except any and all feedback!

Comment: Nice job for your first question. Very well done :-)

Comment: I think Tchitchikov's answer is on the right track, but it's a bit weird that you call the method `.colliderect` on `pygame.Rect`, which is not an instance of `Rect` but the class Rect itself.  However, I don't know why this would give you the particular error message that you got.  Did you really mean `self.rect.colliderect(drone.rect)`?  BTW I agree with Ken White that it's a good question and well presented.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks!

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thank you so much! The error is finally gone! xD

Comment: Side comment, I think if you are not exactly comfortable coding using OOP, code procedurally first and then re-organize your code later. But if you insist, give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title: A rect style object is a `pygame.Rect`, a tuple or a list with 4 elements. So you can usually pass a 4-tuple or list to methods that expect a `pygame.Rect` as well.

---

As Paul Cornelius mentioned, the exception is raised because you use the `colliderect` method of the `pygame.Rect` **class**, but should instead use the `colliderect` of the `self.rect` **instance**.

```
self.c = self.rect.colliderect(drone.rect)
```

You can actually use `pygame.Rect.colliderect` directly and pass the two rects that you want to check, but that's unusual and would be a bit confusing for everyone else.

```
# `self.rect` is passed as the `self` argument.
self.c = pygame.Rect.colliderect(self.rect, drone.rect)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't have any experience with Pygame, but with a little searching it seems the problem you are having is a result of passing an improper argument to your `pygame.Rect.colliderect()` on line 79. The object you are passing the `pygame.Rect.colliderect()` method is not being read as a `Rectangle` object. Try printing the object `drone.rect` data and object type to see where the problem might be.

Comment: Ok, I printed drone.rect, and it printed 'rect(0, 0, 32, 32)' with the same error message after that. So, I think it is a rect style object, but now what?

Comment: See my comment, just posted.  If the argument drone.rect is OK, look at the other object involved (pygame.Rect).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the advice, it helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Paul Cornelius is in the right direction. Since you're learning python I'll explain briefly. The colliderect method is implemented in C:

```
static PyObject*
rect_colliderect (PyObject* oself, PyObject* args)
{
    PyRectObject* self = (PyRectObject*)oself;
    GAME_Rect *argrect, temp;
    if (!(argrect = GameRect_FromObject (args, &temp)))
        return RAISE (PyExc_TypeError, "Argument must be rect style object");

    return PyInt_FromLong (DoRectsIntersect (&self->r, argrect));
}
```

Since you called it through the class definition and not an instance, `drone.rect` was assigned to `oself` by the python wrapper to this method, and `args` was probably assigned some equivalent of `NULL`. Hence the error message you saw (and not a 'missing required positional argument' as one would expect).